# Creating and Running intellij JAR file works perfectly within intellij, however running standalone JAR uses no resources

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I've created a game in IntelliJ and I'm trying to create an executable JAR for said game. The JAR compiles fine and runs fine, however it's a blank screen and only uses my score(which, when coded using JAVA Swing was using default fonts and no images).

Here is said image of the above
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw02Q.png) [Image of blank screen when running standalone jar], I've also confirmed that the resources are indeed within the JAR file

When I run the JAR file in IntelliJ using run configurations, or even just right clicking where the jar file was(from IntelliJ sidebar), it uses the jar perfectly fine and runs it fine as well.

Here are said images of how the game is supposed to look.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snkr7.png) [running jar from intelliJ]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkRpH.png) [begin screen]

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rGX1.png) [ingame]

[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YLXz.png) [end screen]

Comment: You should provide more details. How do you load your resources (include the relevant code in your question)? What project structure do you have (including configuration of project modules and build artifacts)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.